# RestSharp GetAsync ignores response error status codes

Tags: error-handling, restsharp, http-status-codes

The comment on RestSharp's `GetAsync<>` method explicitly mentions:

> Execute the request using GET HTTP method. Exception will be thrown if the request does not succeed.

I'm not sure how to interpret that. I'd expect it to throw an exception when a non-succes HTTP status code is returned. This does not seem to be the case. When a 404 or 500 status is returned, the method happily tries to deserialize the response. Only when the response body contains invalid json (or xml, or whatever is 'accepted') will an error be thrown.

Am I missing something? How should I, using these async methods, handle such error responses?

Comment: As an example of how it *should* be done, and how I expected it to work, have a look at how the Flurl HttpClient does it: https://flurl.dev/docs/error-handling/

Answer (score 3):

That behavior threw me off too.

Looking at the source code for [RestClientExtensions at GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/src/RestSharp/RestClientExtensions.cs), the `GetAsync`method is implemented as:

```
public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync<T>(request, cancellationToken);
    ThrowIfError(response);
    return response.Data;
}
```

You would expect that `ThrowIfError`would look at the HTTP Status Code, but looking at [RestSharp documentation for error handling](http://restsharp.org/usage/exceptions.html), it says:

> If there is a network transport error (network is down, failed DNS
>   lookup, etc), RestResponse.ResponseStatus will be set to
>   ResponseStatus.Error, otherwise it will be ResponseStatus.Completed.
>
> If an API returns a 404, ResponseStatus will still be Completed.

Which you can confirm by looking at `ThrowIfError` implementation:

```
static void ThrowIfError(IRestResponse response)
{
    var exception = response.ResponseStatus switch
    {
        ResponseStatus.Aborted   => new WebException("Request aborted", response.ErrorException),
        ResponseStatus.Error     => response.ErrorException,
        ResponseStatus.TimedOut  => new TimeoutException("Request timed out", response.ErrorException),
        ResponseStatus.None      => null,
        ResponseStatus.Completed => null,
        _                        => throw response.ErrorException ?? new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    };

    if (exception != null)
        throw exception;
}
```

As for your question:

> How should I, using these async methods, handle such error responses?

You can't :(.

I believe you would have to implement your own async implementation of `Get<T>`.

Here's an example of what I did:

```
private Task<T> GetAsync<T>(RestRequest request)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var response = client.Get<T>(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessful)
            return response.Data;

        //handle the errors as you wish. In my case, the api I work with always
        //returns a bad request with a message property when it occurs...
        var errorData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiMessage>(response.Content);
        throw new Exception(errorData.Message);
    });
}

public class ApiMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
public Task<MyModel> SomeRequest()
{
    var request = new RestRequest()
    {
        Resource = "some-resource",
    };

    return GetAsync<MyModel>(request);
}
```

Source:

Answer (score 1):

Use `RestClient.ExecuteTaskAsync()` method instead which gives you access to useful properties of `IRestResponse` such as `StatusCode`, `ErrorException` & `ErrorMessage` etc